# Set maxHeight for a ViewGroup

Tags: android, height, max, viewgroup, layoutparams

A `ViewGroup` has a property called `minHeight` which allows you to set the minimum height of the `ViewGroup`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:minHeight

There is no property called maxHeight.  So how exactly can you set the maxHeight of a `ViewGroup`?  It seems that you must do something in the `ViewGroup`'s overridden methods and not in XML.  I attempted to do something like this in `onMeasure()` but had no luck.  Does anyone have any ideas?

#### Update

Specifically, I want to set `height="wrap_content"` while also setting a maxHeight of a
[FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout/issues/10)

But the views within the `FlowLayout` are not being displayed.

Answer (score 2):

you have to override `onMeasure()` and call `setMeasuredDimension`. For instance

```
    setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), mMaxHeight);
```

where mMaxHeight can be a fixed value, or you can loop on the ViewGroup's children, measure them, and calculate this value